# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+2009^x}\frac{\sin(2010x)}{\sin(2010x)+\cos(2010x)}\,\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: definite-integrals

Any hints for this one please?

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+2009^x}\frac{\sin(2010x)}{\sin(2010x)+\cos(2010x)}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: Wish I could use $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$?

Comment: I tried that but it's not helping very much..

Comment: The integrand function is NOT integrable in a neighbourhood of a point $x$ for which $\sin(2010 x)+\cos(2010 x)$ vanishes.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? The use of years ($2009, 2010$) is highly suggestive that this is from a college math competition. I have checked Putnam 2008-2011; this does not appear there.

Comment: Source: near the bottom of http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=3433157&postcount=272

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And aren't there a infinitely many of those points? It would seem this integral is "duly divergent"…

Comment: Given $n$, there exist a $(\tau,\rho)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x+\tau)-\rho$ is an odd function over $I=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Assuming that $f(x)\in L^1(I)$ (this is not the case, anyway) we just have $\int_I f(x)\,dx = \pi\rho.$

Comment: See the [answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741580/integral-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac12007x1-cdot-frac-sin2008x-si).

Comment: @Lucian, Would you mind sharing your solution once you are done

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Are you saying that this integral cannot be solved by the same method as the one I linked to ?

Comment: @Lucian, Frankly speaking I could not, but I'm eager to learn an elementary solution of this problem

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment of @Jack D'Aurizio: when does 
$$
 \sin \left( k x \right) + \cos \left( k x \right) = 0?
$$

Examine the plot for the case when $k=1$.

[image: problem]

Given integer $j$, the roots are
$$
 x_{-} = \frac{-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2j \pi}{k}, \qquad 
 x_{+} = \frac{\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2j \pi}{k}
$$

Over the domain, there $2010$ roots for $x_{-}$ and another $2010$ roots for $x_{+}$.

The figure below zooms in on one of these $4020$ singularities.

[image: sliver]

**Answer**

Integral is not defined.