# $ \int \frac{\sin^{a}x}{\sin^{a}x+\cos^{a}x}dx$ and $ \int \frac{\cos^{a}x}{\sin^{a}x+\cos^{a}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I tried solving this integral:

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \frac{1}{2007^x + 1}\frac{\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x+\cos^{2008}x}dx$$

I took a while before aptly applying the following identity I had noted down in my notebook before..
$$\int^m_{-m}\phi(x)dx=\int^m_0\phi(x)+\phi(-x) dx$$

And my hunch was right; I managed to get it to a 'manageable' form:
$$I_1=\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x+\cos^{2008}x}dx$$

---

This got me wondering..

***Does there exist a closed form for the following integrals?***

$$ I_2=\int \frac{\sin^{a}x}{\sin^{a}x+\cos^{a}x}dx$$$$ I_3=\int \frac{\cos^{a}x}{\sin^{a}x+\cos^{a}x}dx$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I've changed my question.

Comment: @Kugelblitz, Once marked duplicate, I think, better ask for an independent question instead of changing

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Please remove the duplicate sign; I've changed the question.

Comment: But why? @labbhattacharjee I was just following your suggestion; since you redirected me to the duplicate.. Besides, those two integrals were also part of my question; you can check it in the edit yourself!!!!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you sir; I will try harder to prevent duplicates next time!

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741580/integral-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac12007x1-cdot-frac-sin2008x-si

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Ahh... So integrals $I_2$ and $I_3$ are equal?

Comment: *[Here](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/integration-bee-challenging-integrals/)* is a solution for your problem.

Comment: @ARUNA No, that's the solution for the problem I was working on; I need help in evaluating $I_2$ and $I_3$

Comment: @Kugelblitz, Are $I_2,I_3$ indefinite versions of some definite ones?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee As far as I know, no. I just thought of these generalized integrals after having tried to solve the question you initially marked duplicate.